# Display: table and text-align right not working

Tags: html, css, text-align

I've got a html-structure like this:

```
<div class="campain">
    <div class="campainText">
        <a href="#"><h2>Ny app til iPhone og iPad</h2></a>
        <a href="#"><h2>Tips og vinn</h2></a>
    </div>
    <div class="campainPicture">
        Picture goes here
    </div><div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

And I'd like the campainText to be right-align. The css for this element is this:

```
font-family: 'Spinnaker', sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #A2AD00;
display: table;
padding: 4px;
margin: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
text-decoration: none;
```

I know that the rest of the css is working. The problem is that the text is left-aligned if I include the table-option in the display-field. As soon as I remove this, it works as expected. Are there any workarounds for this, or do I have to use display: inline and `<br />` tags?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xbNCZ/**

*"Table + `text-align:right` does not work"*, because a table element doesn't stretch to the full width by default. Add `width:100%` to get the desired result.

[Before](http://jsfiddle.net/xbNCZ/1/) / [After](http://jsfiddle.net/xbNCZ/) setting `width:100%`.

Comment: For the text-align to work you should set a width on the element, but any width will do, it does not necessarily have to be 100%.

Comment: @Jan-Henk Smaller widths won't produce the desired result. The OP requested a width which equals the size of an ordinary `div` element, which is `100%`.

Comment: I just added this comment as a side note as to explain why the text-align property did not work, and that was because no width was set. You are right that the OP needs a width of 100%.

Comment: Is your fiddle supposed to show the solution? Because aligning text left doesn't work in your fiddle.